# What is the double sample problem in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

According to the [SBEED: Convergent Reinforcement Learning with
Nonlinear Function Approximation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.10285.pdf) for convergent reinforcement learning, the Smoothed Bellman operator is a way to dodge the double sample problem? Can someone explain to me what the double sample problem is and how SBEED solves it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double sampling problem is referenced in Chaper 11.5 *Gradient Descent in the Bellman Error* in [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (2nd edition)](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html).

From the book, this is the full gradient descent (as opposed to semi-gradient descent) update rule for weights of an estimator that should converge to a minimal distance from the Bellman error:

> $$w_{t+1} = w_t + \alpha[\mathbb{E}_b[\rho_t[R_{t+1} + \gamma\hat{v}(S_{t+1},\mathbf{w})] - \hat{v}(S_{t},\mathbf{w})][\nabla\hat{v}(S_{t},\mathbf{w})- \gamma\mathbb{E}_b[\rho_t\nabla\hat{v}(S_{t+1},\mathbf{w})]]$$
>
> [...] But this is naive, because the equation above involves the next state, $S_{t+1}$, appearing in two
> expectations that are multiplied together. To get an unbiased sample of the product,
> two independent samples of the next state are required, but during normal interaction
> with an external environment only one is obtained. One expectation or the other can be
> sampled, but not both.

Basically, unless you have an environment that you can routinely re-wind and re-sample to get two independent estimates (for $\hat{v}(S_{t+1},\mathbf{w})$ and $\nabla\hat{v}(S_{t+1},\mathbf{w})$) then the update rule that naturally arises from gradient descent on the Bellman error does will work any better than other approaches, such as semi-gradient methods. If you can do this rewind process on every step, then it may be worth it because of the guarantees of convergence, even in off-policy with non-linear approximators.

The paper proposes a workaround for this issue, keeping the robust convergence guarantees, but dropping the need to collect two independent samples of the same estimate on each step.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot approximate $ E^2(x)$ by $\frac{1}{N} \sum_i x_i \frac{1}{N} \sum_j x_j $. Because $cov(x)=E(x^2)-E^2(x)$.

Comment: Hello. This answer is quite short. Maybe you could elaborate a little bit more and tell us more in detail how this answers the question(s). For example, how does this answer the question "what is the double sample problem"?